# fetching hierarchical data

Tags: sql, oracle

i have table like:

```
emp id | post  | manager id
----------------------------
1       | l1   | 2
2       | l2   | 3
4       |l1    | 2
3       | l3   | null
-----------------------------
```

I have a another table like:

```
emp id | target achived | given target | 
----------------------------------------
1      |  200            |  300
---------------------------------------
4      |  400            | 500
```

I have a function which make a notification, like

```
l1 id----target achived/target given
```

1       ,   200     /300
4       ,   400    /500

(above mentioned notification emp id 2 will get, who is a l2)
all l2 will get notification like this.

l3 will get sms of l2 only
for given case l2 target achived =all target achived by his all l1

so emp id 3 will get like--------

```
empid 2--- 2, 600/800
```

how to design the query is generalized way that depth of hierarchy may be anything.. actual work is done by l1 only.
notification will be like--
l2 will get result of his own l1 only.
l3 will get result of his own l2 (sum of result of corresponding l1) and corresponding l2 sms also...so on.....

Comment: if i use  query like----select target achived,target given from  targettable where emp id in (select emp id where manager id =2 from emptable)

Comment: for l3 query will be like select sum(target achived),sum(target given) from targettable where emp id in (select empid from emptable where manager id=3)----for l3 and higher hierarchy this will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oacle you have "Connected by" to run hierachical queries.

Here is a link to AskTom about this subject. You can also google "Oracle Connected By".

[CONNECT BY basics](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:489772591421)

I don't have Oracle installed so I cannot test it but this is how you can get the achieved/target totals by manager:

Get the hierarchical results for the manager's reports by manager.
Get the stats for each manager as if they were their own bosses so as to to include the info in their own report.
Union the two sets of information.
And summarize the information by manager.

Again the query may have typos but the stratergy presented should work.

```
select sum(c_achieved), sum(c_target), c_manager
from
(
  -- Get the metrics of each manager's reports
  select all_info.t_achieved c_achieved, all_info.t_target c_target, all_info.manager c_manager 
  from
    (select emp_id, post, manager, t_achieved, t_target 
    from emps, targets
    where emps.emp_id = targets.emp_id) all_info
  start with all_info.manager is null
  connect by prior all_info.emp_id = all_info.manager
  union
  --Get the metrics of the managers to add them to themelves
  select all_info2.t_achieved, all_info2.t_target, all_info2.emp_id
  from 
    (select null, post, emp_id, t_achieved, t_target 
    from emps, targets
    where emps.emp_id in (select distinct manager from emps) all_info_2
  where all_info_2.emp_id = all_info_2.manager
) stats_by_manager
group by c_manager
```

Comment: How comnected by will help here pls help to make the query